# Passing data between two controllers using storyboards

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, storyboard, segue

I am trying to pass data from one `UITableViewController` to another. This is my code in the initial view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
Subject *subject = (Subject *)[self.fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[self showList:subject animated:YES];
[self.tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
}

- (void)showList:(Subject *)subject animated:(BOOL)animated {
ListsViewController *lists = [[ListsViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStyleGrouped];
lists.subject = subject;
NSLog(@"%@", lists.subject);

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}
```

The log output was showing that it had the data I wanted had been passed over. However when I perform the segue and log the `subject` in the `ListsViewController` is shows null.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to overwrite `prepareForSegue:sender:` method. The quick fix would be

```
- (void)showList:(Subject *)subject animated:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:subject];
}
```

...

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        ListsViewController *controller = ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ListsViewController class]]) ? segue.destinationViewController : nil;
        controller.subject = ([sender isKindOfClass:[Subject class]]) ? subject : nil;
    }
}
```

The reason why your code did not work is that in your `showList:animated:` method you created a `ListsViewController` instance and assigned it a `subject`, but this view controller was never presented. Instead `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` creates another instance of your `ListsViewController` class which knows nothing about your `subject`. That's why you need to wait for UIStoryboardSegue to instantiate a destination view controller from the storyboard and then configure it the way you want, which you can do in `prepareForSegue:sender:` method.

Also it might be not the best idea to use `subject` as a sender in `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender` method, because it's just not the sender :). What I would do is create a property subject in your view controller class and use it `prepareForSegue:sender:`

```
@interface MyViewController ()

@property (strong, nonatomic) Subject *subject;

@end


@implementation MyViewController

- (void)showList:(Subject *)subject animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    self.subject = subject;
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        ListsViewController *controller = ([segue.destinationViewController isKindOfClass:[ListsViewController class]]) ? segue.destinationViewController : nil;
        controller.subject = self.subject;
    }
}

...
@end
```

Comment: It's worth to know how a life cycle of a segue looks like. Documentation is [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/featuredarticles/ViewControllerPGforiPhoneOS/CreatingCustomSegues/CreatingCustomSegues.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007457-CH16-SW1).

Answer (score 0):

Implement prepareForSegue and pass date in this methos

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
if([seque.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"])
{
ListsViewController *lists = seque.destinationViewController;
lists.subject = subject;
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

That's good, but now you need to add this:

First instead of:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
```

You need to send the object:

```
[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:subject];
```

Add a property in your ListsViewController.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) Subject * subjectSegue;
```

And now in your first view controller:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        ListsViewController * lists = (ListsViewController *)[segue destinationViewController];
        lists.subjectSegue = sender;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand that `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` creates a new instance of view controller. So the `ListsViewController` that you have created is not the being displayed on the screen.

You need to override `prepareForSegue:sender:

```
- (void)showList:(Subject *)subject animated:(BOOL)animated 
{
  [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"showDetail" sender:self];
}

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"showDetail"]) {
        ListsViewController *controller = (ListsViewController *)segue.destinationViewController;
    controller.subject = self.subject;
}
```